# Problem with using list comprehension to transform based on two lists. Error 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to transform based on two lists using `zip` as follows. But i am getting `'int' object is not iterable`. Help is appreciated. Here is the snippet. `y` and `y_predicted` are each lists of length 10.

```
errors = [sum((i-j)**2) for i,j in zip(y, y_predicted)]
```

Comment: show your actual `y` and `y_predicted` inputs

Comment: `sum((i-j)**2` is the issue, you are summing a single number

Comment: should probably be `sum((i-j)**2 for i, j in zip(y, y_predicted))`. but hard to tell without more details.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see the problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(i-j)**2` is an integer. If you try to `sum()` an integer, you will receive the error.

You probably want to just `sum` the whole thing, right?

`sum((i-j)**2 for i,j in zip(y,y_predicted))`